# stringify selected ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a select option box and it's options (ng-options) are generated from an array within the $scope:

```
<select ng-model="formData.method" ng-options="method.name for method in methods | orderBy: 'name'"></select>
```

formData is parsed server-side and the problem I'm having is that the value chosen from the select element gets passed as an object rather than a string. eg: `method: { name: 'Shaken' },`

I'm pretty new to Angular but am I missing something that will stop this from happening? It should just read `method: Shaken,`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define [`ngOptions`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) as `value as label for object in arrayOfObjects`:

```
ng-options="method.name as method.name for method in methods | orderBy: 'name'"
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/Uz49bwBVBpxf6CUjSHwN?p=preview